# IMAP UID FETCH BODY.PEEK[] command response

Tags: email, imap, fetch, mime, uid

I'm now developing a simple IMAP-client. To recieve message body I'm using command "UID FETCH *message-UID* BODY.PEEK[]". The question is can I be sure that one of the server responses on the command will be "* *message-sequence-number* FETCH (UID *message-UID* BODY[] *message-body*)"? Or should I be ready to recieve any possible FETCH response (like with message envelope)? I know that I can recieve message flag updates in form of "* *message-sequence-number* FETCH (FLAGS *flags*)", I just ignore it now.

Of cause, I've read the standard [rfc3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501), but did not find out the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't be sure that the message exists. But if it does exist, then the server has to send you a FETCH that includes both UID and BODY[], usually but not necessarily in that order. In practice it may also include FLAGS but nothing else.

Comment: could you tell me the part of standard which describes it?

Comment: The bottom half of page 54. It's a bit on the terse side, if you ask me, though. The RFC doesn't say "cannot return other stuff", but compatibility with a thousand fragile clients demands that ;)